# C++ code crashes instantly due to memory issues

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

This code should read a `.pnm` file. I tried to run it with 2 resolutions:

- 200x200 px: Here everything works just fine.
- 500x281 px: Code instantly crashes, raising a `SIGSEGV` error.

As far as I know, `SIGSEGV` is related to memory issues. I have 8GB of RAM, a quantity that I judge to be enough to run this. I don't have any idea about why it's happening and how to fix it.

### Code

```
#define IO_ERROR                (5)
#define X_DIMENSION             (500)
#define Y_DIMENSION             (281)
#define C_DIMENSION             (3)
#define HEADER_SIZE             (3)
#define BODY_SIZE               (X_DIMENSION * Y_DIMENSION * C_DIMENSION)

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int readImage(string fileName, string *imgHeader, string *imgBody)
{
        ifstream inputFile(fileName);

        if (!inputFile.is_open())
                return IO_ERROR;

        string line;
        int count = 0;
        while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
                if (line.find("#") != string::npos)     
                        continue;
                if (count < 3)                          
                        imgHeader[count] = line;
                else                                    
                        imgBody[count - HEADER_SIZE] = line;
                count++;
        }
        inputFile.close();

        return 0;
}


void numericParser(const string *imgBody, unsigned char *numericBody)
{
        int i = 0;
        while(i < BODY_SIZE) {
                numericBody[i] = (unsigned) atoi(imgBody[i].c_str());
                i++;
        }
}

void rgbParser(const string *imgBody, unsigned char rgbMatrix[X_DIMENSION][Y_DIMENSION][C_DIMENSION])
{
        unsigned char numericBody[BODY_SIZE];
        numericParser(imgBody, numericBody);
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < X_DIMENSION; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Y_DIMENSION; j++) {
                        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                                rgbMatrix[i][j][c] = numericBody[k];
                                k++;
                        }
                }
        }
}

void printInfo(const string *header, const string *body)
{
        cout << "#-*- Image Header -*-" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < HEADER_SIZE; i++) {
                cout << header[i] << endl;
        }

        cout << "#-*- Image Body -*-";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 * C_DIMENSION; i++) {
                if (i % 3 == 0) cout << endl << "R: " << body[i];
                else if (i % 3 == 1) cout << " G: " << body[i];
                else cout << " B: " << body[i];
        }
        cout << endl << ". . ." << endl;
}


int main()
{
        string fileName;
        cout << "File name: ";
        cin >> fileName;

        string imgHeader[HEADER_SIZE];
        string imgBody[BODY_SIZE];
        if(readImage(fileName, imgHeader, imgBody) == IO_ERROR)
                return IO_ERROR;

//        printInfo(imageData);

        unsigned char rgbMatrix[X_DIMENSION][Y_DIMENSION][C_DIMENSION];
        rgbParser(imgBody, rgbMatrix);

        return 0;
}
```

### Additional Info

I'm on Arch Linux 64-bit, using CLion as IDE.

Comment: There could be a stack overflow - typical implementations offer 1 MB of stack by default. You could increase the stack size using an OS command, or use static or dynamic allocation for your large arrays

Comment: `readImage` should check that it does not write out of bounds of the output arrays

Comment: The code does not reach ```readImge```. Crash occurs before ```cout << "FIle name: "```

Comment: I will try to increase the stack

Comment: Did you determine the location of the crash using a debugger?  I would bet that it doesn't crash there, but you're assuming this because you don't see the program output this text.  You might not realize the output is buffered and not yet flushed when your program crashes later on.

Comment: Yes, it happens on the very beginning, before it asks for a name file

Comment: I used the IDE debugger to find out where it crashes

Comment: [Stop on brakpoint](https://ibb.co/ddKcdJ).
[Step into...](https://ibb.co/gofiJJ).

Comment: Definitely looks like a stack overflow.  Use static or dynamic memory allocation for your large array instead, as suggested by M.M.

Comment: @AugustoDias *I have 8GB of RAM, a quantity that I judge to be enough to run this* -- Wrong.  That is not the way to judge whether this is enough memory.  You're creating local stack variables that more than likely exceed stack memory, which is most of the time 1MB.  Use `std::vector` instead of giant arrays.

Comment: It's not a memory leak if it crashed before the very first `cout` statement. @M.M stack size is a limitation of threads; main() has heap size available. Unless Arch does something different... @Augusto Dias see if you have `ulimit` set to a small value?